# Displaying the value returned, linked to the other two arrays of of information

Tags: arrays, methods, indexing, return

//Is there a better way of displaying the returned information, without having to write the everything I wrote in the S.O.P. The goal is to return the value then link it to the name and time of the racer. Thanks for your help.//

```
public class array_Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String[] names={"Bob", "Tj", "Aj"};
        double [] times={9.9,9.8,10.0};
        double x=findLargest(times);

        System.out.print("The slowest racer was " + names[1] + " with a time of " 
        + times[1] + " at index position" + x);
}
    public static double findLargest(double[] times)
    {
        int indexOfLargest=0;
        double largest=times[0];
        for(int i=0; i<times.length; i++)
        {
            if(times[i]>largest)
            {
                largest=times[i];
                indexOfLargest=i;
            }
        }
        return indexOfLargest;                      
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use *class* ? You can merge the names and the times of the racers with something like that :

```
public class Racer {

 private String name;
 private double time;
 private int position;

 public Person(String name, double time){
 this.name = name;
 this.time = time;
 this.position =-1;
   }

 public String getName() {
   return name;
   }

 public double getTime() {
   return time;
   }

 public int getPosition() {
   return position;
   }

 public void setPosition(int position) {
   this.position = position
   }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
   return "The slowest racer was " + getName + " with a time of " 
    + getTime + " at index position" + getPosition);
   }        
}
```

This class allow you to manage easlier your "Racer" and the override of the function *toString()* allow you to customize your *printl()*.

You can now change your code with this :

```
public class array_Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Racer[] people ={new Person("Bob",9.9),new Person("Tj",9.8),new Person("Aj",10.0)};

        double x=findLargest(times);

        System.out.print(Racer[x].toString());
}
    public static double findLargest(double[] times)
    {
        int indexOfLargest=0;
        double largest=people[0].getTime();
        for(int i=0; i<people.length; i++)
        {
            if(people[i].getTime()>largest)
            {
                largest=people[i].getTime();
                indexOfLargest=i;
            }
        }
        people[indexOfLargest].setPosition(indexOfLargest);
        return indexOfLargest;                      
    }}
```

Comment: Awesome. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out ! Thank you.